# Error in Saving Lat/Long

Tags: php, mysql

Whats the error in my code? I just want to save the markers lat/lng in PHP XAMMP

```
<form method="post">
<input id="userLat" type="text" name="userlat"  />
<input id="userLng" type="text" name="userLng"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value = "save"/>

   <?php
    if($_POST["submit"]=="Save")
    {
         $userlat = $_POST['userlat'];
    $userLng = $_POST['userLng'];

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_connect_db("dbmarker");

    $s="insert into tblmarker (lat,long) values('".$userlat."','".$userlng."')";
if(mysql_query($s))
echo "record saved";
else
echo mysql_error();
}
?>

var ll = markerA.getLatLng();
document.querySelector('#userLat').value = ll.lat;
document.querySelector('#userLng').value = ll.lng;
```

the event here is that when i place a marker in my map, its lat/long will show in textbox and i will save it in database but its not saving

Comment: What is happening? What errors do you get? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Actually i dont see an error when i click the button save the webpage will reload but after i see my table there is no lat/long saved. I want to save the lat/long that has been transfer to textbox to a database

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). This is especially horribly bad since you're using the mysql root account with **NO** password on it. As well, there's no function `mysql_connect_db()`, so your code will never work anyways.

Comment: i already edited my codes but still nothing happens

Comment: is it fixed or not? 
if not try to change `if($_POST["submit"]=="Save") to if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`

and at the very top add `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes around your `$_POST` keys.

```
 $fname = $_POST ["fname"];
 $lname = $_POST ["lname"];
```

If there are no single or double quotes, php recognize `fname` and `lname` as constants, what you definitely do not has.

NOTE:

- Do not use mysql functions they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
- Avoid sql injection by escaping your variables, or use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli` instead

change

```
    $userlat = $_POST[userlat];
    $userLng = $_POST[userLng];
```

to

```
    $userlat = $_POST['userlat'];
    $userLng = $_POST['userLng'];
```

Comment: sir i already edited my codes with the code that you want to change but still its not working

Comment: I still dont know what to do my code posted has the code you want but when i try it, its not saving in database